# Can I explicitly set Magento 1.9 Order Increment ID on Creation

Tags: magento-1.9

Is it possible to change / set the order increment ID "on the fly" while creating orders?

This Inchoo post shows me how to create an order https://inchoo.net/magento/programmatically-create-order-in-magento/

But I cannot seem to find how to change / set the number programmatically.  ( I don't just want to set a sequence )

thanks for your time.